# Layer disappears from map after CRS changed in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers

I have 3 layers and a basemap. 2 layers align nicely with the google basemap and accept it´s CRS which I have set as a project CRS and also enabled on the fly reprojection. I have also selected it as a default CRS and ticked the ´use project CRS´ in SETTINGS - OPTIONS - CRS. These are all options I have found reading people´s comments.

However when I add the third layer it does not appear on the map. It will only appear if I change the CRS back to it´s original one which is different to the one the other layers are in. I have also tried saving this layer with the desired CRS and re-opening it but still won´t appear.

The CRS I want to use for the project is ESPG 3857 or ESPG 4326 but the layer only accepts Krovlak.

Any tips on how else I could proceed?

Comment: that is how it is supposed to work, one of your layers is in a different projection than the rest. Turn OTF on and set the **project** CRS to the one you want

Comment: Load each layer one by one into qgis, save each one into the same CRS, then load all of them into the same project and things should work out.

Comment: It sounds like the third layer crs is not defined correctly, otherwise it would align with the other different crs layers with the "on the fly re-project"  setting enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Does it not appear, or does it appear in the wrong place..?

Regardless, I've had a similar problem. The way I've fixed it is by the method in Erik's comment - load each one in one by one, then save each into your desired projection.